# Why does using the ternary conditional operator yield a "return_of_invalid_type" error?

Tags: dart, types, casting, conditional-operator

`func` yields an error - `A value of type "Object" can't be returned from the function 'func' because it has a return type of 'B'.` Why this error specifically? Shouldn't both `C()` and `D()` be considered to fit `B` and therefore have the ternary expression evaluate to an instance of `B`? If not, why does the ternary expression evaluate to an `Object` and not an instance of `A`? This error does not occur using regular conditional syntax (`if`/`else`).

```dart
class A {}

class B {}

class C extends A implements B {}

class D extends A implements B {}

B func(bool b) => b ? C() : D();
```

Comment: Given that it works for `if`-`else`, it's probably a bug that the conditional ternary operator does not resolve the common base type in the same way.  I recommend [filing an issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/).

Comment: I have now done so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a known issue - see the issues linked here: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/2577